# Including Script Tag in Html button

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to development and am looking to include an src = .js in my form, to return data instead of forwarding it to, as included in my form, google.

Where should I put my script tag, and how can I alter my form to redirect to the .js instead of google?

```
<form target="_blank" action="https://google.com" id=searchbar >
  <div class="inner-form">
    <div class="input-field first-wrap">
      <div class="svg-wrapper">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Paste a domain here" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-field second-wrap">
      <button class="btn-search" action="https://www.google.com" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="info">ex. JeepBeef.com</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Include the script after the from, then use `document.getElementById('searchbar').addEventListener('submit', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); /* more code here */ });`

Comment: What do you mean by redirect to .js? It sounds like you need to use an event listener that overrides the normal form submission and calls a function.

Comment: @ChrisG Would the Javascript then go in the * more code here* ? Not sure how that would call a specific js function?

Comment: @Barmar how would the event listener be able to call the function?

Comment: You put the function call in `more code here`

Comment: That code *is* the JavaScript.

Comment: @Barmar Do you have an example of proper function call?

Comment: `document.getElementById('searchbar').addEventListener('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); yourFunction(); })`

Comment: This will call `yourFunction` when the user clicks the submit button.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, but I have a separate .js file, let's call it sweep.js, where it has my function identified and built out. Apologies but unsure how I can call on that through the 'yourfunction' ... could it just be an src=?

Comment: `<script src="sweep.js"></script>` loads the function. You can then call it from other `<script>` tags on the page.

Comment: It sounds like you need to read a tutorial on using JavaScript in web pages.

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/atfqu6dn/